# How to log all firestore operations using cloud logging?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-logging

It looks like there is a service for **logging all read/write** operations in *Firestore*:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging

I have billing enabled, as well as the `Cloud Storage for Firebase API` with read/write data access. (the api keys are also ip restricted, so that the db won't be abused)

[IAM -> Audit Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs7xv.png)

In cloud logs, I perform this query:

```
logName=("projects/{my-project}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access" OR "projects/{my-project}/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity")
```

But I still can't see any of the read/write operations.
Are the queries wrong? Anything else?

Comment: Do you have activated the audit logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Firestore, enable the Audit Logs under `Firestore/Datastore API` in the IAM -> Audit Logs page.

`Cloud Storage for Firebase API` does not apply to Firestore.